# Passing Expression to IEnumerable Select

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, expression, ienumerable

I am trying to write custom mappings from db entities to application read models.

Let's suppose I've got 2 entities

```
public class A
{
    public string One {get; set;}
    public string Two {get; set;}
    public ICollection<B> Three {get;set;}

}

public class B
{
    public string SomeProp {get; set;}
    public string SomeProp2 {get; set;}
}
```

I am trying to map those entities to read models.

```
public class AReadModel
{
    public string One {get; set;}
    public string Two {get; set;}
    public ICollection<BReadModel> Three {get;set;}
    public bool Deletable {get; set;}

}

public class BReadModel
{
    public string SomeProp {get; set;}
    public string SomeProp2 {get; set;}
}
```

The entity B in this relation is Collection yet in another it can be standalone 1 : 1 or 1 : 0 realtionship so i would like to define mappings between A and AReadModel and B and BReadModel as Expressions which will be passed as IQueryable Select(). The point is I would like to reuse my mapping for B -> BReadModel in defintion of A -> AReadModel and define it as a IQueryable custom extension.

```
public static class BMapping
{
    public Expression<Func<B,BReadModel>> expression = instance => new BReadModel
    {
        SomeProp = instance.SomeProp,
        SomeProp2 = instance.SomeProp
    };

    public static IQueryable<BReadModel>ToReadModel(this IQueryable<B> source)
    {
        return this.Select(expression);
    }
}

public static class AMapping
{
    public Expression<Func<A,AReadModel>> expression = instance => new AReadModel
    {
        One = instance.One,
        Two = instance.Any,
        Deletable = Three.Any(),
        Three = instance.Three.Select(BMapping.expression) // this will not work cuz Three is collection and it requires Func<B,BReadModel> yet i need an expression here, otherwise EF won't be able to translate it. Of course I could just explicitly define mapping here again and it would work but it will lead to maintenance hell.

    public static IQueryable<AReadModel>ToReadModel(this IQueryable<A> source)
    {
        return this.Select(expression);
    }
}
```

So the question is: Is it possible to reuse mapping defined in BMapping in Mapping definition for nested collection in AMapping?

Comment: Check out LinqKit. http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx

Comment: why don't you just use normal EF and then use AutoMapper to transform to your custom classes. But what i would like to know.. is what are you trying to achieve.. why the ReadModels in the first place?

Comment: @Seabizkit The answer is very simple. EF with Lazy Loading let's you download only Data Included in Entity. Let's suppose that Three Collection is mapped to a Table and the size of this collection (table) will increase at least in linear manner during application runtime (like A is a Test and B is a TestInstance). So One Test can have thousands of Test Instances.  I do not want to download such a large collection along my Entity yet I need some data that can be calculated only on this collection. (Example: Deletable = Three.Any()) (cheap on DB expensive on app side)

Comment: In another words ReadModels let me move a lot of calculations to Database and build by ReadModel by only one query to db + i protects myself from unintentional downloading to app large collections to app from db (by that i mean calling Any on Three Collection on Entity Downloaded by simple query which would result in downloading Three Collection just to check it's emptiness).

Comment: @user2184057 what has lazy loading got to do with anything i said. you have a entity with a collection of entities... ok, now your worried about volumes.. ok, but you don't really explain where the issue is. filter what you need and only use that.. simple. Try explain in simple terms what you are trying to over come... looks like handling large volumes...are you abstracting some detail in your question "lots of calulations" how are these stored. could you update with a use case of the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it requires some expression post processing like [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) `AsExpandable` / `Invoke` / `Expand`, but fortunately in this specific case you can simply use `AsQueryable` before applying expressions, which is supported by the latest EF6.

So, assuming `exppression` is a static member of `BMapping` class, the following should work:

```
Three = instance.Three.AsQueryable().Select(BMapping.expression)
```

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Compile()` method of `Expression` class which returns corresponding delegate (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345362(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: The problem is EF does not work on Delegates -> It works on Expression, If i will use compile i lose all information about expression tree which EF requires. (It will parse expression tree and won't be able to translate method call ToReadModel).

Comment: This question isn't about making code compile but rather passing this expression in a manner which will allow Entity Framework to translate it later on.